# How to assign different versionCode for multiple architecture apks built with flutter

Tags: android, flutter

My [`pubspec.yaml`](https://github.com/raag-music/raag/blob/b3b7bf0e0acd4a01a028484edad4d22b2f225a1d/pubspec.yaml#L5) has version code 11.

Building a fat apk with `flutter build apk` gives an apk with `versionCode` 11 as expected. But building an `armeabi-v7a-release` apk gives an apk with `versionCode` 1011 instead of 11.

I would like to change the behaviour of incrementing 1000 to the versionCode of armeabi-v7a as mentioned in android's [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-APK-versions) (Thanks to [@Varun Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11299632/varun-kumar) for pointing it). I want the `armeabi-v7a` apk to have the versionCode corresponding to that mentioned in `pubspec.yaml`. How do I edit [this build.gradle](https://github.com/raag-music/raag/blob/master/android/app/build.gradle) to achieve the same?

Comment: This is the default behavior. Read more here https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-APK-versions

Answer (score 0):

Figured that it's possible to override the output .apk file's `versionCode` by adding code to the `build.gradle(:app)` as mentioned in [android's documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-APK-versions) that allows us to explicitly modify the logic followed to assign `versionCode` for each abi.

For avoiding the 1000 increment made to armeabi-v7a alone, I modified the logic of the inner if block to the following:

```kotlin
        if (baseAbiVersionCode != null ) {
            output.versionCodeOverride =
                    baseAbiVersionCode * 1000 + variant.versionCode

            if (baseAbiVersionCode == 1) { // Matches armeabi-v7a in ext.abiCodes
                // Uses the default versionCode for armeabi-v7a APKs.
                output.versionCodeOverride = variant.versionCode
            }
        }
```

NOTE: This part is a little hacky as you might end up having the same `versionCode` for both the fat apk and the armeabi-v7a ABIs. I would recommend using this only if you want to target one ABI exclusively.